# How can I get Mandrill to display an image based on MERGE value?

Tags: if-statement, dynamic, mandrill

I'm coming up short with merge tags to display the dynamic content needed (Images). I've tried every which way that I think I can. Here's the code...where am I messing up?

```
*|IF:VAR_VEH_TYPE=Cat|*
    <p><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/617278/pexels-photo-617278.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"></p>
*|ELSEIF:VAR_VEH_TYPE=Dog|*
    <p><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/356378/pexels-photo-356378.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"></p>
*|ELSEIF:VAR_VEH_TYPE=Bird|*
    <p><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534695941753-73cf13435eb4?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"></p>
*|ELSEIF:VAR_VEH_TYPE=Fish|*
    <p><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/128756/pexels-photo-128756.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"></p>                                          
*|ELSE:|*
    <p>alternate content to display if the value for MERGE is not x, y, or z</p>
*|END:IF|*
```